# visual studio issue syntax error with combining string to number

Tags: python, visual-studio

currently having some issues with visual code that dont make sense.
tried printing out the following sentence in python:

```
 count = 0
 message = f"We have {count} even numbers."
 print(message)
```

With the following error:

```
message = f"We have {count} even numbers."
                                        ^
invalid syntax
```

I'm just wondering what the correct would be, do i need to add a + around the count like java?

Comment: what python version do you use? f-string was introduced in python 3.6

Comment: @luigigi 3.6 to be more specific

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using a version that is under 3.6, if so, use `%s` string formatting:

```
count = 0
message = "We have %s even numbers." % count
print(message)
```

Or use `str.format`:

```
count = 0
message = "We have {} even numbers.".format(count)
print(message)
```

Comment: Tbh, im currently utlising python 3.8.1, though your method words monica. thanks for the help, but i think part of the reason is that visual studio is utilising the python 2.7 found in mac. do you have any idea how i can check the version of Python being utilised by visual studio.

Comment: @J.Doe By using `import sys;print(sys.version)`

Answer (score 0):

It works even for pyhton 3.5 or less

```
num = 10
string_data = "you have {} apples.".format(num)
print(string_data)
```

Comment: I'm currently running python 3.8.1.

Comment: It worked with 3.8.1 as well. there must be some issue with dev-environment you are using.